# Wait for a SQL in Phonegap in order to return the object generated

Tags: javascript, sql, function, cordova

I want to create a general function for selecting data from my database. When I call the function `query_general(query_var);` from my main code index.html, where `query_var` is the query, it doesn't return anything. Then I call this again and it returns me the previous result.

It is as if JavaScript doesn't wait for `db.transaction(queryDB_general,errorCB_general1);` to be finished and returns the previous result or nothing the first time used.

I know using intervals is not recommended, but intervals don't work either.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("example_db", "1.0", "Example", 500000);
var general_query;
var general_result={};    

function queryDB_general(tx) {         
  tx.executeSql(general_query, [], querySuccess_general, errorCB_general);
}

function querySuccess_general(tx, results) { 
  general_result=results;
}

function errorCB_general(err) {
  alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code+" message: "+err.message+" query:"+general_query);
}
function errorCB_general1(err) {
  alert("Error 1 processing SQL: "+err.code+" message: "+err.message+" query:"+general_query);
}

function query_general(query_var) {
  general_query=query_var;
  db.transaction(queryDB_general,errorCB_general1);
  return general_result;
}
```

Comment: you should learn about async javascript, the sql query takes time, so when you return general_result it doesn't have any value yet, you won't have a value until the querySuccess_general, that is the place where you should put the code you want to execute once the query is run and return the value

Comment: Totally agree @jcesarmobile , that is what exactly happens. How could I return the value `general_result=results;`, I've tried `return results;` but I don't know how to catch this value in the previous function `queryDB_general` and finally in `query_general` in order to retun this to the original caller. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: you can't return values on async functions, you have to use the callbacks, where you'll have the values

Comment: Could you edit my code and use callbacks please? :) I would really appreciate it @jcesarmobile

Comment: There is nothing to edit, querySuccess_general is the place where you have the results, pass them to any funcion you like as param or put there the code you want to execute with the results

Comment: Oky I'll try that. Thank you @jcesarmobile